# Unable to find Google Chrome DevTools of Overrides to show Emulator tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using Google Chrome **Version 49.0.2623.87 (64-bit)** on **OSX 10.10.5 (14F1605)**. Tried to find **Overrides** tab to show Emulator. I had also tried after cleaning all user data from PC & installed a newly downloaded Chrome dmg package, but no luck. Is there any reason to hide **Overrides** or **Emulator** tab. Attached image for reference. [image: No Emulator tab] [image: No Overrides tab here]

Comment: Re-reading this question now I don't understand what it is asking exactly. Can you please be more clear? That way I can verify that my answer is in fact responding to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is so the drawer panels are able to be kept minimal to what a developer needs to be there. More can also be added later without necessarily adding more panels in the way for everyone. Just toggle what you need and be happy.